# Pylint: same pylint and pandas version on 2 machines, 1 fails

Tags: pandas, pylint

I have 2 places running the same linting job:

Machine 1: Ubuntu over SSH

- pandas==1.2.3
- pylint==2.7.4
- python 3.8.10

Machine 2: Gitlab CI Docker image, `python:3.8.12-buster`

- pandas==1.2.3
- pylint==2.7.4
- Python 3.8.12

The Ubuntu machine is able to lint all the code fine, and it has for many months. Same for the CI job, except it had been running Python 3.7.8. Now that I upgraded the Docker image to Python 3.8.12, it throws several `no-member` linting errors on some Pandas objects. I've tried clearing CI caches etc.

I wish I could provide something more reproducible. But, to check my understanding of what a linter is doing, is it theoretically possible that a small version difference in `python` messes up `pylint` like this? For something like a `no-member` error on Pandas objects, I would think the dominant factor is the `pandas` version, but those are equal, so I'm confused!

### Update:

I've looked at the Pandas code for `pd.read_sql_query`, which is what's causing the `no-member` error. It says:

```
def read_sql_query(
    sql,
    con,
    index_col=None,
    coerce_float=True,
    params=None,
    parse_dates=None,
    chunksize: Optional[int] = None,
) -> Union[DataFrame, Iterator[DataFrame]]:
```

In Docker, I get `E1101: Generator 'generator' has no 'query' member (no-member)` (because I'm running `.query` on the returned dataframe). So it seems Pylint thinks that this function returns a generator. But it does not make this assumption in my other setup. (I've also verified the SHA sum of `pandas/io/sql.py` matches). This seems similar to [this issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1161), but I am still baffled by the discrepancy in environments.

Comment: Do any of the envs have pylint config files?

Comment: If there are interpreter dependent branches in pandas (``if sys.version_info ...``), the same pandas version could be parsed differently depending on the python interpreter by pylint.

Comment: @richardec, yes, they are using identical versions of the codebase, which includes a `.pylintrc` file that used in the linting command.

Comment: I am still unsure why the difference in Python versions seems to be causing this, but a fix that worked was a setting like `max_inferred=500` in my `.pylintrc` file, as explained [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/4577). @Pierre.Sassoulas, since you are in that linked thread!

Comment: I think you can answer your own question @dcc310

Answer (score 0):

A fix that worked was to bump a limit like:

```
init-hook = "import astroid; astroid.context.InferenceContext.max_inferred = 500"
```

in my .pylintrc file, as explained [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/4577).

I'm unsure why/if this is connected to my change in Python version, but I'm happy to use this and move on for now. It's probably complex.

(Another hack was to write a function that returns the passed arg if the passed arg is a dataframe, and returns 1 dataframe if the passed arg is an iterable of dataframes. So the ambiguous-type object could be passed through this wrapper to clarify things for Pylint. While this was more intrusive on our codebase, we had dozens of calls to `pd.read_csv` and `pd.real_sql_query`, and only about 3 calls caused confusion for Pylint, so we almost used this solution)